# ActiveMQ: view the content of the enqueued messages

Tags: activemq-classic

I am using ActiveMQ with web console (activemq-web-console-5.16.4) in TomEE. The ActiveMQ-web-console-5.16.4.war was added to the TomEE webapps folder. Afterwards, I could access the web console. Currently, I want to view/monitor the content of enqueued/processed messages in the web console "Messages Enqueued". How can I manage that in my case? Should I bind the KahaDB message store or other databases?

In my application I use Apache Camel and send messages from one route to another by ActiveMQ.

I would appreciate any help.

**Screenshots:**

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the web console itself to view the content of the message assuming it fits into the narrow constraints of what the console can decode into human readable format.

First, click the "Browse" link.
[image]

Second, click the link for the actual message.
[image]

Third, see the "Message Details."
[image]

To be clear, you can only inspect the content of messages which are *in the queue*. This is represented by the "Number of Pending Messages." The "Messages Enqueued" is the number of messages *sent* to the queue (but not necessarily in the queue currently) since the broker was started. The "Messages Dequeued" is the number of messages consumed from the queue. In your case you have 66 messages which have been enqueued and dequeued (i.e. consumed) and therefore 0 pending messages.

If you want to keep a copy of every message sent to your queue for auditing purposes you can use a [mirrored queue](https://activemq.apache.org/mirrored-queues.html). As noted previously, you can only inspect messages which are *in the queue* and a mirrored queue will hold a *copy* of every message sent to the source queue allowing you to inspect those messages at your convenience.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I have already tried it before but when I clicked on browser I do not see any messages. The enqueued messages in my case are 66. I added some screenshots for more details. In your first screenshots the Test queue has 0  enqueued messages in my case I have 66 enqueued messages. In the scecond screenshot, you have many messages. In my case I do not see any message of the 66 enqueued messages?!

Comment: I updated my answer to address your comment.

Comment: Actually, I want to see the enqueued messages if it is possible somehow (in my case the 66 enqueued messages). I knew before that I can see the pending messages.

Comment: Unfortunately you can only see details about messages that are actually _in the queue_ (i.e. "pending" messages).

Comment: Is not possible to view the enqueued messages if I bind the KahaDB message store or  backup the message into databases? Like describe in this link: https://livebook.manning.com/book/activemq-in-action/chapter-5/18

Comment: Can not I manage it by using the mirror queue? as described in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23666405/is-it-possible-to-mirror-a-single-queue-in-activemq

Comment: I'm not sure how a KahaDB backup would work in this case, but you can certainly use a mirrored queue. However, even in that case you can still only see details about messages that are actually _in the queue_ (i.e. the mirror queue in this case). I updated my answer with more details.

Comment: "Pending Messages" _are_ the "Enqueued Messages". Those are messages stored in the KahaDB.

Comment: That's right. In short, all pending messages have been enqueued, but not all enqueued messages are pending (i.e. ones which have been consumed). That said, only persistent messages would be stored in KahaDB.

Comment: Thank you for your support! I managed it by the mirrored queue. Does that mean that the messages copies in the mirror queue are stored in the kahaDB too?

Comment: If the messages are persistent, yes.